# Vaadin declarative Grid caption via Annotations

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

While browsing through the source for `Vaadin 7.6.1` i recognized, that there is no way of defining a column header based on an annotation, when using a `BeanItemContainer<?>`. Is there a way around this?

Imagine a simple CRUD application with 2 entity beans `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
public class Foo {
  private String interface_;
  private String uag;

  // Omitted getters / setters
  // ...
  }

public class Bar {
  private String forename;
  private String lastname;


  // Omitted getters / setters
  // ...
  }
```

When passing this beans to a `BeanItemContainer<?>` it creates magically deep inside Vaadin following column headers:

- Interface_
- Uag
- Forename
- Lastname

Is there a way around this and name generated properties after an `Annotation` for example? Is there a reason why this is not implemented? Just for curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item properties in the **BeanItemContainer** are determined automatically by inspecting the getter and setter methods of the class.

As far as I know there is no way to work with annotations for that case. You can define your getters/setters the way you like to control the property naming.

Comment: Where did you find this functionality?

Comment: you can look it up [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-container.html), hope this helps you further